# Java timer task first run

Tags: java, linux, timertask

I have a Java timer task for generating daily reports. When I invoke a Java class (that schedules that timer task) through linux terminal, instead of scheduling the first run at the given time it runs as soon as command is executed.  Can someone please suggest why is it so ..

I am using scheduleatfixedrate for scheduling it.

Forgot to add that I am using java 1.5 
[Here is the method def](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#scheduleAtFixedRate%28java.util.TimerTask,%20java.util.Date,%20long%29)

Code snippets:

```
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new ArchiveTask(), archiveSchedule, 86400000);

public class ArchiveTask extends TimerTask {

public void run() {
        backUpFiles();
    }

public void backUpFiles(){
            ...}
}
```

Comment: Maybe try a `ScheduledExecutorService` instead?

Comment: are you sure that archiveSchedule is different than zero?

Comment: make sure that the second argument is greater than zero and is significant enough that you notice the difference. the second argument specifies when should the first execution begin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add to what i said earlier, here is the working code:

```
public class Test {
static Timer timer = new Timer();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new timeTask(), 10000, 10000);
}

private static class timeTask extends TimerTask {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("inside task");
    }

}
}
```

Comment: I am using Java 1.5 (sorry should have add that in the question)         http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#scheduleAtFixedRate(java.util.TimerTask, java.util.Date, long)

Answer (score 0):

The problem as suggested by dreamer was this that the second argument was 0.